# Need help adding source dir to bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to run this script I found in a book:

```
#!/bin/bash
# copydir.sh

E_NOARGS=85

if [ -z "$1" ]   
then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` directory-to-copy-to"
  exit $E_NOARGS
fi  

ls . | xargs -i -t cp ./{} $1

exit 0
```

I want to copy a text file from desktop to the home dir using this script, but every time I insert the source argument it ignores it and starts copying the whole ubuntu folder to my home dir. I am running bash on windows 10, and as I said I am a total newbie. If anyone could help and tell me how to pass the source and copy-to dir argument to this script I would be thankful.

Comment: `cp /path/from/source /path/to/destination` that is the basic syntax of `cp` you can ignore `xargs` for now. Also you really don't need to add a hard coded exit status on your scripts. Let it be the actual exit status.

Comment: https://shellcheck.net is a good site for validating scripts, and don't use/parse `ls` for scripts, it is not a good idea.

Comment: @Jetchisel Thank you for the reply, i tried the normal syntax you mentioned. Entered the destination as ~/folder1 and got the error no such file or directory even tho the folder exists in my home dir.

Comment: try  `"$HOME/folder1"`

Comment: @Jetchisel thank you,that destination works with the syntax. So if i can copy the files with only cp command what is the use of this script in the book?

Comment: There are several things wrong with that script, but basically the whole thing can be replaced with `set -o nounset && cp ./* "$1"` unless you have literally thousands of files.

Comment: @Adisx, that script is broken by design, don't use it. Combining `ls` and `xargs` is not a good to start your scripting journey.

Comment: always quote your variables until it does not do what you expected it to do, not the other way around.

Comment: If your instructor wrote the book -- find a new instructor -- quickly... You have two options for finding the absolute path for a directory name that exists, either `realpath name` or `readlink -f name` (you can try both with, e.g. `readlink -f .`) You also want to validate that the destination directory exists or otherwise create it, e.g. `mkdir -p "$dest" || exit 1` where `$dest` contains the path to your desired destination. `$HOME` will always exists, but for all others -- check. You generally don't want to pollute the base of your `$HOME` directory, consider using a subdirectory.

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: I edited the script by removing "ls" and adding "-r" after "cp". Now when i execute the script and pass the destination argument it asks me to specify the source. And when i do, the copying executes successfully. Thank you everyone for the tips.